# How to configure a single Azure B2C Application for different sites under Sitecore?

Tags: azure

How to configure a single Azure B2C Application for different sites under Sitecore, the b2c can reply on single domain but we have around 70 different domain

Comment: First of all, welcome to amazing Sitecore Community Sandeep! Could you please be more specific and specify your problem more in detail?

Comment: Is your question about, how to configure Azure B2C Tenant to accept request from 70 different domain in multi-site environment? If yes, please describe it properly in your question. i might be able to provide the answer.